# Open url in Webbrowser without www. in C#

Tags: c#, web, process, uri

I have a program where you can enter a word and it opens the wikipedia article.

This is my code(`input` is my word):

```
string url = "http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + input.Replace(" ", "_");
Process.Start(url);
```

But when I start the website with `Process.Start(url)` it starts "http://www.de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYZ" instead of "http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYZ"

How can I open a website without the `www.`

Kind regards

Comment: The browser probably receives a 302 redirect and follows it. It is not your code, it is how the site works.

Comment: My browser (chrome) redirects to https://, some browsers may act differently.

Comment: I have chrome too

Comment: Use the chrome dev tools to view the network communication. You'll be able to see if the initial request is without "www" and then a redirect was requested.

Comment: The above comments are good points, you can also manipulate the string if you prefer it to be a certain way, for example: `string url = url.Replace("www", string.Empty);`. However, I believe you should leave it as the site redirects it. This way, all users know exactly what address is the proper one. Edge for example, stores the proper address, and removes the `https://www` even if you type it in (from my understanding), but if you click in the address bar, that information is displayed.

Comment: I know programs which can open wikipedia sites. Why cant mine?

Comment: The problem is that www.de.wikipedia.org does not work

Comment: Is it giving you an error?

Comment: Hell I'm stupid

Comment: I use the code above two times and in the one I tested contained "www."

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what is actually happening here? I am lost as to what the issue is; from my understanding, it doesn't even display the page.

Comment: So I tried this in a test application just passing in the website you listed above, the website was opened in Microsoft Edge and displayed the same as it did in Internet Explorer. Is the issue that you just don't wish to see the `www` portion?

Comment: I found the problem

Answer (score 0):

you should try to start your chrome and pass the URL as an argument:

```
            Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "--app=http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/");
```